# MSAccess 2010: Selecting multiple rows of a one to many relationship

Tags: ms-access-2010

I have tried to find an answer to this but so far have not been successful.

I have two tables in Access 2010: (1) Activities and (2) Dependencies. The ***Activities*** table essentially contains a list of activities and their durations. The ***Dependencies*** table specifies what activities are dependent on what other activities. The (simplified) table definitions are:
**Activities**
ID
Activity
Duration

**Dependencies**
ID
ActivityID
DependsOnID

When entering an activity, I would like to have a multi-select combo or listbox on the form that will let me select, from the already entered activities, those which must be done before the one I am entering. For example, if I have entered in the ***Activities*** table

> ID Activity
>    1    A
>    2    B
>    3    C
>    4    D
>    5    E

and I am now entering activity F (which in this example has an ID of 6) and which depends on activities C and D, I would like to be able to select C and D from the combo and have it populate the ***Dependencies*** table so that it has (ignoring the ID key column in the ***Dependencies*** table)

> ActivityID  DependsOnID
>         6            3
>         6            4

Is this something that can be done at the time of entering the activity, or do all the activities have to be entered and then a second pass made to assign all the dependencies?

Or is there a better way of achieving what I am after?

I realize this is a somewhat artificial example but I am thinking this sort of scenario might apply when entering products where you might want a list of Related Products.

TIA

Answer (score 0):

I think what you want is a multi-select combobox containing the dependencies. 
[image: multi-select combobox]
It's in this article from the Office support website (https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Use-a-list-that-stores-multiple-values-c8d15127-3641-45fc-aa2d-a3943d355e89) that explains how to implement it.

I used it in a number of scenarios and it helped my implement simpler input forms in which the user adds an entity and checks the multi-select combobox for related records in another table. In your case - the user will be able to add the activity and the list of dependent activities in one form.

Good luck!